# Converting a positive integer to have a negative value

Tags: java, negative-number

So today in class we had to make a program that asked to input values between or equal to -25 and 25, and to quit the program when a number outside those values is entered. When I try to input any number higher than 25 or a negative value, the program crashes and an error report pops up.

So here's my question, how to make these negative values work. I included the program below to help anyone you is willing to help figure this problem out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int occurrences[] = new int [51];

        System.out.println ("Enter integers in the range if -25 through 25.");
        System.out.print ("Signal end with a");
        System.out.println ("number outside the range.");

        int entered = scan.nextInt();       
        while (entered >= -25 && entered <= 25)
        {
           occurrences [entered] ++;
           entered = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println ("Number\tTimes");
        for (int check = -(25); check <= 25; check++)
            if (occurrences [check] >= 1)
                System.out.println (check + "\t" + occurrences [check]);

    }
}
```

Comment: "the program crashes and an error report pops up" it never, ever, hurts to include the very specific error message you get, along with the line number!

Comment: Wow. There are at least two problems with this code, and anyone who doesn't answer BOTH of them gets downvoted *immediately*. Territorial much? Answer retracted.

Comment: @John I didn't downvote you, but judging by the amount of random downvotes on my other answers, you might want to cool down a bit :)

Comment: @John - There's a problem with negative subscripts. Judging by your answer, you thought that not using `hasNextInt()` is a problem. However, the spec is that the program should expect only a series of integers; using `hasNextInt()` is unnecessary since dealing wtih non-integer input is outside the requirements (and perhaps a topic for a future assignment for OP). (Or was your second problem with the code something else?)

Comment: @TedHopp I see no such assumption anywhere in the question. Without an explicit statement saying that only integers will be input, your assumption is invalid. Are you perhaps the professor of this class, and have a more detailed spec than we got?

Comment: @John - The first sentence of OP's post strongly suggests that the only inputs will be numbers. No behavior is specified for when the input is not a number, so quitting with an exception is as reasonable as any other behavior (including quitting silently). I would also point out that your (now deleted) answer had two problems: it was calling `scan.nextInt()` an extra time at each loop iteration when the number was within bounds and would not exit when a number out of bounds was entered.

Comment: @TedHopp Maybe you are correct about the "implied" requirement. It just so happens that the first problem that caught *my* eye was that user input was coming through unchecked. The question asker did not provide a listing of his input, so there *could* very well be an error than nobody here can even see that would otherwise be glaring. You have to admit than an input error could completely disguise some of the more intricate problems. Since he did not provide the error message, you can't say I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on line

```
occurrences [entered] ++;
```

Negative numbers cannot be used as indices to an array. In order to fix this, you can use a separate variable to track the number of scanned values, such as `count` and use this to access the array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can't use negative numbers to index into a Java array.

You could shift array indices like so:

```
    occurrences [entered + 25] ++;
```

This will remap the numbers from -25 to 25 as 0 to 50, allowing them to be used as array indices.

(You'll need to change the rest of the program accordingly; I leave this as an exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 1):

Array indices cannot be negative. So a dirty solution (but working) would be to add 25 to value entered before using it as array index. This will work for negative numbers but not for nurber > 25. To use such values, you need to use a larger array or use a different method of storing the values.